# Gesture conflict with a Slider object in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, slider, gesture

I have an iOS app using SwiftUI. It has pages which I can swipe (using SwiftUIPager). This is working pretty well, but I have a Slider object on some of the pages, and this is where troubles show up. Moving the slider conflicts with the swipe gesture of the page and this is not what I want.
I should be able to move the slider without the underlying page moving.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import SwiftUIPager


struct XplainString: Identifiable {
    var id:Int //{return id}
    var value:String
}


struct PageView: View {
    .....
    @StateObject var page:Page
    .....
    
    var body: some View {
        Pager(page: self.page,
              data: self.itemsList,
              id: \.self) { page in
                self.pageBlock(page)
        }
        .swipeInteractionArea(.allAvailable)
    }
    
    
    func pageBlock(_ page: PageList) -> some View {
        VStack {
            .....
            SliderBlockView()
                .padding(.bottom, 17)
        }
    }
}


struct SliderBlockView: View {
    .....
    @State private var sndSpeed = 100.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: Binding(get: {self.sndSpeed},
                                  set: {newValue in self.sndSpeed = round   (newValue)}),
                   in: 0...100)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .padding(.horizontal, 3.0).padding(.vertical, 2.0)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0)
                    .stroke(lineWidth: 7.0)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray))
                .padding(.horizontal, 20.0).padding(.top, 20.0)
            
            HStack {
                .....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work correctly in iOS 14.4 and Xcode 12.4 @Michel

Comment: I am using iOS 14.4.2 and Xcode 12.4, it is not working well for me. More precisely, it is working rather well when I move the slider left but very bad when I move it right.

Comment: I just noticed another detail. After reaching a page, I can use the slider fairly smoothly, if I remove my finger and then want to use the slider again, it become hard and there is a conflict with the page swiping.